# django URLs MultipleObjectsReturned error

Tags: python, django

I am making a simple webapp with Django. A user can have a profile, and under that profile create a blog post.

For example:

```
"path('profile/<int:pk>/',profile, name='profile')"
```

Returns the URL

```
"http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/1/"
```

A user can then write blog posts which have the name in the URL

Example:

```
path('profile/<int:pk>/blog/<str:name>',Blogs, name='Blogs'),
```

Returns the URL

```
"http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/1/blog/HelloWOrld"
```

However, IF two different users both name their blogs the same exact name, i get a 'MultipleObjectsReturned' Error.

I thought that by having the user PK earlier in the URL it would ensure that it would be unique, even if two blogs were called the exact same thing.

**Views.py**

```
def Blog(request, pk, name):
    blog = Restaurant.objects.get(name=name)
    user = CustomUser.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if not user.id == request.user.pk:
        raise PermissionDenied()
    else:
        context = {
            'user': user,
            'blog': blog,
        }
        return render(request, 'blog/blogs.html',context)
```

IS there any way to work around this without using the PK of the blog as well?
And if anyone could explain why my logic was wrong and it wasn't working in the first place.

Thanks.

Comment: Show the code how you filter

Comment: @shafik, I have edited the question to include the Views,py

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure you get the blog of that name *of that user*. I don't know exactly how your blog models look, but it's going to be something like

```
user = CustomUser.objects.get(pk=pk)
blog = Restaurant.objects.get(name=name, user=user)
```

And on the model, use the 'unique_together' property to ensure that the *combination* of user and blog name are unique, otherwise these URLs aren't going to work. Having the name completely unique as in George's answer isn't necessary and would mean that users couldn't create blog posts with titles already made by another user.

Comment: Great Answer, Thanks very much! Solved the issue (And future issues) well. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You need to make `name` field unique, and use [SlugField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#slugfield) for this if you want to use [clean url](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_URL):

```py
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, ...)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, ...)
    ...
```

Comment: For functions naming, use snake_case pls, and use django.shortcuts.get_object_or_404.